# Mock repository used by JPQL query while testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to test CRUD Repository with related JPQL:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRolesRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRoles, Long> {

@Query("SELECT a.role FROM UserRoles a, UserEntity b WHERE b.username=?1 AND a.id=b.id")
public List<String> findRoleByUserName(String name);
}
```

My problem is to mock repository related to UserEntity. I've tried to mock methods of user repository, but them seem not to be ever called.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = BlogCmsApplication.class)
public class UserRolesRepositoryTest {
@Autowired
UserRolesRepository userRolesRepository;
@Mock
UserRepository userRepository;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

}

@Test
public void findRoleByUserName() throws Exception {
    UserEntity user = new UserEntity("user467","somepass");
    user.setId(1);
    Mockito.when(userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername())).thenReturn(user);
    Mockito.when(userRepository.findOne(user.getId())).thenReturn(user);
    Mockito.when(userRepository.exists(user.getId())).thenReturn(true);


    UserRoles role = new UserRoles(1,"ROLE_USER");
    userRolesRepository.save(role);

    List<String> actualRole;
    actualRole = userRolesRepository.findRoleByUserName(user.getUsername());

    List<String> expectedRole = new ArrayList<>();
    expectedRole.add(role.getRole());

    assertNotNull(actualRole);
    assertEquals(expectedRole,actualRole);

}
```

With `@Autowired` works fine but it's not the point.
Assertion error is

```
Expected :[ROLE_USER]
Actual   :[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `@MockBean` here,  Spring Boot includes a @MockBean annotation that can be used to define a Mockito mock for a bean
inside your ApplicationContext. You can use the annotation to add new beans, or replace a single
existing bean definition. The annotation can be used directly on test classes, on fields within your test,
or on @Configuration classes and fields. When used on a field, the instance of the created mock will
also be injected. Mock beans are automatically reset after each test method.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Transactional
public class SpringBootJPATest {

    @MockBean
    private BlogEntryRepository blogEntryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void jpa_test() {
        BlogEntry entity = new BlogEntry();
        entity.setTitle("Test Spring Boot JPA Test");
        BlogEntry persist = entityManager.persist(entity);
        System.out.println(persist.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void jap_test_repo() {
        BlogEntry entity = new BlogEntry();
        entity.setTitle("Test Spring Boot JPA Test");
        BlogEntry persist = blogEntryRepository.save(entity);
        // System.out.println(persist.getId()); // This line will get a NPE as the repo is using the mocked bean
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not work for me :/ Throws an initialization error: `java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy`
I've been trying to use @InjectMock, but with no success. 
This query doesn't work properly: `userRolesRepository.findRoleByUserName(user.getUsername())`

Comment: @zfChaos I'm using sprint boot 1.4 here, which version you used?

Comment: 1.3.5 but I've changed to 1.4 to test this solution. 
Console output: `Hibernate: insert into user_roles (id, role, user_id) values (null, ?, ?)`, so this couses trouble with real db.

Comment: @zfChaos You need add the ID generation for your entity, for example, add the `@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;` for the primary key.

Comment: I've got it actually. It works with `@Autowired`.
`@DataJpaTest` causes this error above.

Comment: @zfChaos sorry, you update the question?  please check the Query annonation :-) your sql will return empty result.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I've changed `a.id=b.id` to `a.userId=b.id`, but it still return empty array :/
I keep fighting...

Comment: @zfChaos I'm not sure, but can you update your sql without any paramter, like "SELECT a.role FROM UserRoles a, UserEntity b WHERE b.username=user467 AND a.id=b.id"